# Binary Search Tree, height

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search

this is my height function in bst. cpp

```
int IntBinaryTree::getHeight(TreeNode * nodePtr)
{
  if(nodePtr = NULL)
    return 0;
  else
    return (max(1+getHeight(nodePtr->left), 1+getHeight(nodePtr->right)));
}
```

When I call it in main(). I got an error.

this is my main()

```
int main {
  IntBinaryTree tree;
   .... 
  tree. getHeight(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you are not passing a parameter to your function?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say what error, but looks like changing:

```
if(nodePtr = NULL)
```

to

```
if(nodePtr == NULL)
           ^^
```

is what you need.

Comment: For this reason, it can be a good idea to write comparisons as `NULL == nodePtr` rather than `nodePtr == NULL`. `NULL = nodePtr` (notice the assignment operator) won't compile.